# VIM commenting out what I paste

Tags: vim, vimrc

I got this when trying to copy this gist on vim: https://gist.github.com/w0ng/3278077

[image]

I notice the same behaviour everywhere: If I paste something that includes a comment, everything that follows the comment is pasted commented.

Maybe it has something to do with the fact that if I write a comment on insert mode and press enter, the following line automatically appends a comment.

How can I get rid of this behaviour?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Enter paste mode before you paste:

```
:set paste
```

To switch back to "normal" mode:

```
:set nopaste
```

Comment: or :set paste! to toggle :)

Comment: @valbaca You can use backticks to create `code blocks` in comments

Comment: I needed those commands the opposite way around!

Answer (score 11):

Beside the `paste` option [mentioned by Mat](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84641/15241), you can also directly access the X clipboard from VIM:

- `"*p` to insert the X11 selection
- `"+p` to insert the X11 clipboard

You need a VIM version with X11 support (in Debian and its derivatives you need to install the `vim-gtk` or `vim-gnome` package).

For more information, see the [documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui_x11.html#x11-selection) (`:help x11-selection`).

Answer (score 8):

Here's what's happening. There are Vim formatting options that automatically comment out new lines when you are on a comment line. Some of these options are usually enabled by default. For example,

```
# a comment<CR>
#
```

As you can see, the new line was automatically prepended with a comment character. You can disable the majority of these options by removing `c` and `r` from the setting `formatoptions`. See `:h fo-table` for more information about these options.

```
:set formatoptions-=cr
```

Vim has no way of differentiating between text that is pasted with your terminal emulator's pasting mechanisms and text that you type. Setting the paste options (`set paste`) tells Vim to expect pasted text and disable any formatting options that would be undesirable.

Answer (score 4):

My favorite is using the `put` command.

- `:put*` paste from selection at the current line
- `:put+` paste from buffer at the current line

`"*p`/`"+p` is also good, but `:pu[t]` has some advantages:

- it always pastes linewise
- you can add an additional parameter to control where to insert:

  - `:$put+` paste after the last line
  - `:0put+` paste at the beginning of the file

Answer (score 1):

As a side answer, If you have any files which have this in you can get rid of it by entering Vertical Visual block mode

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and then using arrow keys / hjkl to navigate the parts you wish to delete and then just hitting <kbd>d</kbd>

Sometimes i find this quicker than undo'ing setting paste mode, pasting and unsetting paste mode.

Comment: Is there a downside to permanently disabling past mode?

Comment: Not sure about permanently disabling paste mode (not sure if that's possible) but paste mode is especially powerful if you are pasting a huge amount of text as it prevents Vim/Nvim from attempting to do any automatic behaviors that slow down the paste process. Bracketed paste mode is really handy on Linux/macOS as it can detect large amounts of incoming text and toggle paste mode on temporarily while pasting and then turn it off again automatically.